# RecylerView lag when scrolling without adding image

Tags: android

I added RecyclerView with below adapter and didn't use any image setter . it sets items correctly but had lag when scrolling . I used almost the same adapter in another activity but it worked with any lags

public class TableAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<ItemTableClass> items;
Context mContext;


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView teams, groups, wins, looses, draws, points, plays, differences;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        init();

    }

    private void init() {

        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flagImg);
        teams = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teamName);
        groups = itemView.findViewById(R.id.groups);
        wins = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wins);
        looses = itemView.findViewById(R.id.looses);
        draws = itemView.findViewById(R.id.draws);
        points = itemView.findViewById(R.id.points);
        plays = itemView.findViewById(R.id.plays);
        differences = itemView.findViewById(R.id.difference);
    }
}

public TableAdapter(List<ItemTableClass> items, Context mContext) {
    this.items = items;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.table_item, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int 
    ItemTableClass itemTableClass = items.get(position);

    holder.differences.setText(itemTableClass.
    holder.groups.setText(itemTableClass.
    holder.teams.setText(itemTableClass.
    holder.draws.setText(itemTableClass.
    holder.looses.setText(itemTableClass.
    holder.plays.setText(itemTableClass.getPlays());    
    holder.points.setText(itemTableClass.getPoints());
    holder.wins.setText(itemTableClass.getWins());
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

}

Comment: i dont see any code for loading images.

Comment: yes , some of the same problems was because of that but I don't use .

Comment: @AliBavi i think issue in layout

Comment: @GobuCSG yes , I have too much textViews in my layout . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add this two method in your adapter and try it.

```
 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
     return position;
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return position;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't post a comment so posting in answers.

Pl share R.layout.table_item to see if it contains any complexity. Also share the ItemTableClass so that we could see if there are loads of calculations taking place in your getter methods.

Answer (score 0):

this may occur if you have a complex list items with too many views try to get rid of most of the views and when the user clicks on a list item open a new activity with more details for this item containing all the views required